# Переменная не увеличивается на 1, при правильном условии

Tags: javascript, объекты, variable

Все условия правильные, все проверил. if работает как надо, присваивания тоже.

Но стандартное - `correctAnswerCounter++;`

Не работает верно, оно увеличивается , но неожиданно .
**Весь код скину в конце вопроса**

По идеи при трех правильных ответов , эта переменная должна увеличиваться три раза , то есть в конце она должна равняться **3**, но условие работает иначе.
Переменная равняется **2** . 
В чем ошибка?
Код -

```
"use strict"

// Objects

let question = {
    0: "Какого цвета слон?",
    1: "How many colors?",
    2: "What is that?"
};

let answers = {
    0: {
        1: "grey",
        2: "green"
    },
    1: {
        1: "2",
        2: "3"
    },
    2: {
        1: "foo",
        2: "bar"
    }
};

let rightAnswers = {
    0: 2,
    1: 1,
    2: 2
};

// Counters

let questionCounter = 0,
    questionLimit = Object.keys(question).length,
    correctAnswerCounter = 0;

// Variables

let firstBlock = document.querySelector(".first-block");
let secondBlock = document.querySelector(".second-block");
let pInFirstBlock = document.querySelector(".first-block p");
let pInSecondBlock = document.querySelector(".second-block p");
let questBlocks = document.querySelector(".quest-blocks");
let pQuestion = document.querySelector("#question-p-id");

// Progress-bar

let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progress-bar");
let progressLine = document.querySelector(".progress-bar .progress-line");
let increaseLeft = [];
let leftProcent = Math.floor(800 / questionLimit);

for(let i = 0; i < questionLimit; i++) {
    increaseLeft.push(leftProcent + "px");
}

// Insert p value

pQuestion.innerHTML = question[questionCounter];
pInFirstBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][1];
pInSecondBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][2];

// Add eventListeners

questBlocks.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if(event.target.id == "quest-block") {
        //logs

        console.log(correctAnswerCounter);

        //logic

        progressLine.style.marginLeft = `${"+" + increaseLeft[questionCounter]}`;

        if(questionCounter + 1 != questionLimit) {
            if(event.target.getAttribute("name") == rightAnswers[questionCounter]) {
                questionCounter++;
                correctAnswerCounter++;
                pQuestion.innerHTML = question[questionCounter];
                pInFirstBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][1];
                pInSecondBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][2];
                console.log("correct");
            }else {
                questionCounter++;
                pQuestion.innerHTML = question[questionCounter];
                pInFirstBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][1];
                pInSecondBlock.innerHTML = answers[questionCounter][2];
            }
        }else if(questionCounter + 1 == questionLimit){
            pQuestion.innerHTML = "Ваш результат";
            pInFirstBlock.innerHTML = "Правильных ответов " + correctAnswerCounter;
            pInSecondBlock.innerHTML = correctAnswerCounter + "/" + questionLimit;
        }




    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Счетчик вопросов начинается на 1 (`questionCounter + 1`) и заканчивается на 3. Т.е. делает всего две итерации. Измените условие в нужную сторону нужным вам способом.

Comment: Здравствуйте , но у меня есть проблема. Этот вариант я уже рассматривал , и при **questionCounter != questionLimit**, у меня на последней итерации срабатывает первое условие , а должно срабатывать **questionCounter == questionLimit** , и я вообще не понимаю логику этого условия, хотя оно очень простое

Comment: Просто уберите + 1. Или сделате <=.

Comment: **Дублирую** Проблема в том что переменная должна увеличиваться с первой же итерации, а она начинает увеличиваться со второй .Или я не могу найти ошибку, или это особенность языка

Comment: Да, с таким кодом только и говорить об особенностях языка. Это не особенность языка, ищите ошибку. Чтобы проще было найти - можете сделать трасировку - выводить в консоль значение искомой переменной на каждой итерации и придет понимание.

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev не будем переходить на говнокод, я их вывожу, я понял ошибку но не могу сделать условие

Comment: @mbfilipp извините, погорячился. Но в любой непонятной ситуации - делай доскональный вывод и поитерационно смотри правильно ли выводится. Для этого можно так же составить таблицу с тестовым набором данных. И так делать, пока не придет понимание.

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev уже делал поитерационный вывод, я очень сильно намудрил с задачей, и теперь мозг не вывозит инфу вообще. Буде все переделывать...

Answer (score 0):

```
//}else if(questionCounter + 1 == questionLimit){
}
if(questionCounter + 1 == questionLimit){
```

Comment: Здравствуй. Проблема в том что переменная должна увеличиваться с первой же итерации, а она начинает увеличиваться со второй .Или я не могу найти ошибку, или это особенность языка